# Plugin "Typed Link Field" -> Alternative for Craft 5?

Tags: plugins, control-panel, link, craft5

https://plugins.craftcms.com/typedlinkfield

At first: This plugin was for free and I would like to say "Thank you for you work!" ... thanks Sebastian!

But with a look to 33,291 active installs, I do not think I'm the only one who is thinking about this link topic in Craft 5?

May I ask, what's about your alternatives for this plugin in Craft 5?
This is one option: https://plugins.craftcms.com/hyper
Migration: https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/hyper/docs/guides/migrating-from-typed-link

Anything else?

Comment: We have many sites using this plugin and are trying to decide the best way forward.

Answer (score 4):

You can somewhat replicate it in 5 with an Entry Type and conditional fields that only expose the particular field based on the value ofa dropdown for type selection. I'm not sure how efficient that is in comparison to having a proper field type, and of course you can only use it where you can use Entry Types, but it does "work".

Here's a screenshot of a "Button" Entry Type I have set up, which is itself loaded into a Matrix field and a CKEditor field, and does a bare-bones replacement of the field type for those contexts.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There's several paid plugins, "Link It" is popular and has been around through a few versions of Craft. Hyper is newer but has had good reviews.

I'll also provide a link to the CMS feature request for a native field:
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/9062 please feel free to add to that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Currently my plan is to build a matrix field in Craft5 but I would appreciate it that we have something within the core.